# How to correctly check the event changes after a pointerdown?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have a text input box, and I want to check after I click on the screen, whether the input box is focused or not.

I created an `addEventListener` for the `pointerdown` event to monitor this. Unfortunately, every time I just got opposite result: when I click on the input box, the event listener returns `not focused`, and when I click on the side places to unfocus the input box, the event listener returns `focused`.

I guess the reason is: the event listener will firstly report me the focus status at the moment when I click, then after that the input box will be `focused/unforcused` accordingly. But what I really want is to see what happens after I click. How can I correctly achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to do that? You could of course wrap your code in a setTimeout, or listen to a click event instead of pointerdown, but why not simply listen to the `focus` event from the beginning? Why does it need to be a pointer event?

Comment: Actually click event solved my problem! Thanks!